# View holds an object from the Model in a MVC pattern, is this OK?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have class that holds Tree Items for a Tree.  Say the constructor looks like this `ViewTreeItem(List item)` and can be called like this

```
for( List l : model.getLists() )
    getTree().add( new ViewTreeItem(l) );
```

My controller `ControllerTreeItem` uses the `List item` reference to modify the list directly instead of calling to model to do the work.

Is this OK to change the model in this way?  If not how might I do it in an alternative way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the whole point of MVC is to make the design flexible. i think it would probably be better to have a method in the model which you can use to modify the list instead of modifying directly, as this would negate the whole point of using the MVC pattern.

Comment: Should all model methods call the notifyObservers() method?  or is it ok for them to not notify given a notification is not necessary in a particular case.

Comment: well, you only need to notify the view when you want to display the data to the user. its not necessary to do this if this is not required. because the model is holding the state of the system, so notifying only when you want to display an update view is enough. otherwise, there is unnecessary overhead..

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your view is observing the model then:

1) it is normal for a view to keep a reference to the model.

2) you should change the model by calling methods in the model and update your view when your views onUpdate(Model model) is called.

Comment: Actually this View is not observing the model, because all the tree items get destroyed and refreshed when the notify method is called.  I only do this when a new LIST is selected.